# Appending text to link title on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

So I'm working on my portfolio website. One of the columns has four divs, each with a button inside () that leads to a different page (Resume, Portfolio, Contact, etc). What I'm trying to figure out is how to create a selector of sorts using { and }. I really like the look of brackets around each link, so for instance when you hover over Resume, it would change from Resume to { Resume }. I've been messing with CSS for awhile and got a nice 1s transition on the color, but I have no idea how to get this selector idea of mine to work. I've been attempting to use JS/jQuery to prepend and append { and } to each on hover, but I can't seem to make it work. My JS is definitely on the beginner side, and I haven't seen anything from google searches that helps with this.

Here's the code for the column in question:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-4">
           <div class="resume button links marginTop"><a href="resume.html" class="btn">Resume</a></div>
           <div class="portfolio links button"> <a href="portfolio.html" class="btn">Portfolio</a></div>
           <div class="photography links button"><a href="photography.html" class="btn">Photography</a></div>
           <div class="contact links button"><a href="mailto:me@me.me" class="btn">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
```

And my JS:

```
$(function() {
$('.links').hover(function(){
    var text = (this).text();
    $(this).text = "{ " + text + " }";
});});
```

I'm sure I'm messing up either the HTML or JS (or both), but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be great!

PS: While I'm asking, should I be using a list (UL?) for my links vs. separate divs like I have currently in the column? The links are vertically oriented.

Comment: The problem is your JS. `$(this).text` needs to be $(this).text(<blahbla>)

Comment: Javascript is not the best solution for this. I would just use CSS... EDIT: @mwl posted a great answer

Comment: Really though, the links selector is also wrong. It'll override your links as well @gslette. You've selected the div, not the inner `<a>` element

Comment: @Orpheus yeah I couldn't tell if that was wrong or not. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS only solution: (EDIT: braces placed within the link not around it)

```css
.links:hover a:before {
  content: '{';
}
.links:hover a:after {
  content: '}';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-4">
    <div class="resume button links marginTop"><a href="resume.html" class="btn">Resume</a></div>
    <div class="portfolio links button"> <a href="portfolio.html" class="btn">Portfolio</a></div>
    <div class="photography links button"><a href="photography.html" class="btn">Photography</a></div>
    <div class="contact links button"><a href="mailto:me@me.me" class="btn">Contact</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @gslette just an addendum, you've asked for the braces to wrap the link instead of the text **within** the link. If you want the latter, you need to make a minor change `.links:hover a:before` and `.links:hover a:after`

Comment: So if I want it show up on the page like { Resume } only when they mouseover, I should do the latter? I'll give em both a try and play around with them. Thanks all!

Comment: Just tried it, and @popnoodles had it right. it works perfectly now!!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With brackets inside `<a>`:

```css
a {
    display: block;
}
a span {
    opacity: 0;
}
a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>{</span>Resume<span>}</span></a>
<a href="#"><span>{</span>Portfolio<span>}</span></a>
<a href="#"><span>{</span>Photography<span>}</span></a>
<a href="#"><span>{</span>Contact<span>}</span></a>
```

But I like @mwl's solution with `:before` and `:after` cause in this case you won't be able to select brackets with mouse.